# Create a unique list from two variables in a Linux bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two variables which have values that can be in both. I would like to create a unique list from the two variables.

```
VAR1="SERVER1 SERVER2 SERVER3"
VAR2="SERVER1 SERVER5"
```

I am trying to get a result of:

```
"SERVER1 SERVER2 SERVER3 SERVER5"
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following pipes a combination of the two lists through the `sort` program with the unique parameter `-u`:

```
UNIQUE=$(echo "$VAR1 $VAR2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u)
```

This gives the output:

```
> echo $UNIQUE
SERVER1 SERVER2 SERVER3 SERVER5
```

**Edit:**

As [William Purcell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) points out in the comments below, this separates the strings by new-lines. If you wish to separate by white space again you can pipe the output from sort back through `tr '\n' ' '`:

```
> UNIQUE=$(echo "$VAR1 $VAR2" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' ')
> echo "$UNIQUE"
SERVER1 SERVER2 SERVER3 SERVER5
```

Comment: But note that `$UNIQUE` has newlines for whitespace.  (Try `echo "$UNIQUE"`)

Answer (score 1):

And of course you have

```
$ var1="a b c"
$ result=$var1" d e f"
$ echo $result
```

With that you achieve the concatenation.

Also with variables:

```
$ var1="a b c"
$ var2=" d e f"
$ result=$var1$var2
$ echo $result
```

To put a variable after another is the simpliest way of concatenation i know. Maybe for your plans is not enough. But it works and is usefull for easy tasks. 
It will be usefull for any variable.

Comment: This ignores the bigger part of the question, which is to eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the order, you cannot use `sort`, but you can do:

```
for i in $VAR1 $VAR2; do echo "$VAR3" | grep -qF $i || VAR3="$VAR3${VAR3:+ }$i"; done
```

This appends to VAR3, so you probably want to clear VAR3 first.  Also, you may need to be more careful in terms of putting word boundaries on the grep, as `FOO` will not be added if `FOOSERVER` is already in the list, but this is a good technique.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf '%s\n'` to avoid having to `| tr ' ' '\n`

```
printf '%s\n' "$TEST_VAR1" "$TEST_VAR2" | sort -u
```